# How to delete a remote branch in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Apparently strip only works on local branch but I want to delete a remote branch.

Anything equivalent to these git command for mercurial?
git push origin —delete [branch_name] 
git branch -d [branch_name]

Answer (score 5):

You cannot delete a remote branch ever.

Stripping and hist-editing is a strictly local operation. Thus you need access to the server and strip there (maybe that's possible via web-interface, e.g. on BitBucket).

The only exception is - to some degree - if the changesets are of phase draft AND the remote server is configured a non-publishing server. Then you can obsolete the changesets on the remote server (but not delete them either).

Comment: Yes, that is possible in BitBucket.